# How to get the right text with bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new in bash scripts. I try to make script who check devices ( tp-link, cisco, lynksys... ) to connect via telnet and get some info.

So the first script work with no problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
HOST='IPADDRES'
USER='USER'
PASSWD='PASSWORD'
CMD='enable'
CMD2='show mac address-table'
CMD3='terminal length 0'

(echo "$HOST - " ; (
    echo open "$HOST"
    sleep 1
    echo "$USER"
    sleep 1
    echo "$PASSWD"
    sleep 1
    echo "$CMD"
    sleep 1
    echo "$CMD3"
    sleep 1
    echo "$CMD2\n"
    sleep 30
    echo "exit"
    ) | telnet   ) > name.$NOW.txt
```

When I make: `cat name.date.txt` I get this resulst

```
hostname1 -
telnet> Trying hostname1...
Connected to hostname1.
Escape character is '^]'.
User Access Verification

Username: 
Password:








                 Welcome to BDCOM P3310C EPON OLT




hostname1>enable
hostname1#terminal length 0
hostname1#show mac address-table
        Mac Address Table (Total 311)
------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type       Ports
----    -----------       ----       -----
All     8479.735b.9132    STATIC     CPU
300     44d9.e776.d8b7    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280    DYNAMIC    g0/3
```

So I need export just this line 1 2 and 4
its like this:

```
300     44d9.e776.d8b7    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280    DYNAMIC    g0/3
```

I don`t need anything before
"Vlan    Mac Address       Type       Ports"

So I make this script:

```
cat name.date.txt | awk '$1<"ALL"{print $1"    ",$2"    ",$3"  ",$4}'
```

And I get this result:

```
hostname1    -














             -----------------------------

----     -----------     ----   -----
300     44d9.e776.d8b7     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     0002.9b80.7f28     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     0002.9b65.7b66     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280     DYNAMIC   g0/3
```

Who to fix ?

I just export file only this info:

```
300     44d9.e776.d8b7     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     0002.9b80.7f28     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     0002.9b65.7b66     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea     DYNAMIC   g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280     DYNAMIC   g0/3
```

If will be better if I can export to table or csv

Thanks for answers

Comment: Eeek! Don't use CAPS for variable names in shell scripts. Caps are used for global environment variables so using the same name can cause unexpected issues. For example, `$USER` is a global environment variable set to the current user's name so you _really_ don't want to be changing that in a script.

Comment: Yes, i don`t use USER is like admin or petar
Just for here i put USER

Comment: I am talking about the names of your variables. You should use `$user` not `$USER` and `$host`, not `$HOST` etc. It is bad practice to use CAPS for shell variable names.

Comment: I understand you're right. I will fix it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, but you haven't defined your clear criteria - so I'm mostly guessing here.

If the output you need is consistently in the bottom of your file, you can use `tail` to get the last X lines, e.g.:

```
tail -n 6 name.date.txt
```

... will give you the last 6 lines (the table).

```
Vlan    Mac Address       Type       Ports
----    -----------       ----       -----
All     8479.735b.9132    STATIC     CPU
300     44d9.e776.d8b7    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280    DYNAMIC    g0/3
```

Another option is to use `grep` to search for a pattern, e.g.:

```
grep 'STATIC\|DYNAMIC' name.date.txt
```

... will match those lines that include either the word `STATIC` or `DYNAMIC`.

```
All     8479.735b.9132    STATIC     CPU
300     44d9.e776.d8b7    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     4c5e.0cff.6dea    DYNAMIC    g0/3
300     d4ca.6d9e.3280    DYNAMIC    g0/3
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. The variant "grep 'STATIC\|DYNAMIC' name.date.txt" is perfect for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to print lines from where `$1` is equal to `All` until the end of the file using awk:

```
awk '$1=="All" {p=1; next} p' name.date.txt
```

(omit the `next` if you want to include the matching line).

To make the output comma separated, set the output field separator to "," and force reconstruction of the record by evaluating `$1=$1` for example:

```
awk '$1=="All" {p=1; OFS=","; next} p {$1=$1; print}' name.date.txt
```